# Change Date Using UIStepper

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I am trying to figure out a way to allow a user to change current date represented as a label.

The change/action button is a UIStepper.

The label is defaulting to the current date and when they click the stepper they should be able to change the date to tomorrow, next day, and so on when they click the + on the stepper. Then the opposite for clicking - on the stepper.

```swift
class DateTestViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var stepperOutlet: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let now = NSDate()
        var daysToAdd: Double = 1
        var newDate = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*daysToAdd)
        dateLabel.text = "\(newDate)"
    }

    @IBAction func stepperAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        var unitsValue = 
        dateLabel.text = "\(unitsValue)"
        
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Comment: What "issue"? You are not _doing_ anything about changing the label. And you have not retained the date to go into the label, so there is nothing to change. Also a stepper is not a very good interface choice here... A stepper is about having a value. But you have no value. You would do better to have your own + and - buttons and respond to them.

Comment: Ok thank you for the response Matt. I will look into creating individual buttons for the + and -... and then see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Good, so maintain another `var` property which is the current date value of the label, as a date (NSDate). So when the + button is tapped, do date arithmetic (using NSDateComponents) to increment that date by a day, and then translate that into a string and put it into the label as you are already doing. And so too for the - button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8 • Swift 3 or later**

You can use Calendar method `date(byAdding unit)` to add or subtract the value from your `UIStepper` from your date as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var strDate: UILabel!
    var selectedDate: Date!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectedDate = Date()   // sets the initial date
        strDate.text = selectedDate.formatted
    }

    @IBAction func stepAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        selectedDate = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: .day, value: Int(sender.value), to: Date())!
        strDate.text =  selectedDate.formatted
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var formatted: String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - EEEE"
        return df.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Leonardo! Looks to be working correctly when adding to the date. However, if you try to go to a prior date then the current date it does not work. Example: It will not go any date prior to April 14th.

Comment: You can set UIStepper minimum value to -50 (days) or whatever you want

Comment: Great got it. Created the outlet for the UIStepper then added:   newStepper.minimumValue = -10 Thank you!